# How to make Zig Zag borders using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the zig-zag border.
Like the one in the footer of this page. 
http://kyan.com/
Dunno if thats actually possible with css border-image.

Comment: I don't see the zig-zag border you are talking about on that webpage. Are you sure that is the right example?

Comment: But that page uses it as a background: http://assets.kyan.com/assets/bg_body-371ff50252ac1129efd2aa5d4f4b827b.png

Comment: Thank You Niklas! Sorry for the wrong quetion.!

Comment: @Niklas Post your comment as a reply so it can be accepted :)

Comment: @Joeri - Thought she would remove it instead, but yeah, it might be useful for someone out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page makes it look like a border but it is actually a background image: http://assets.kyan.com/assets/bg_body-371ff50252ac1129efd2aa5d4f4b827b.png

Good idea @Joeri Hendrickx =)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible just use border image
http://border-image.com/